# open modal window

Tags: custom-field, admin-menu, quick-edit, thickbox

I am working on a site where HR employees are managing applicants for jobs. I'm currently trying to add a modal window on a custom admin dashboard that will let a user quickly change an applicant's status.

The dashboard lists applicants by job title, with a few of the more important fields displayed (resume download, the date they applied, etc.):
[image]

Clicking on the "change" button below the applicant's status would open a modal window where the manager could select and save a new value:
[image]

I've figured out how to pass the appropriate post's Wordpress ID into the modal window, but beyond that I'm a bit stuck.

My change button is calling Thickbox, just to make the rendering quicker:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=modal" class="thickbox" id="changeStatus" target="_blank" data-id="<?php echo $app['ID']; ?>"><small>[Change]</small></a>
```

And I have the modal window and script to pass variables in the same applicants.php file:

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>
    <div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <h1>Edit [Applicant Name] Status</h1>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

            <div class="fetched-data"></div>

            <span class="input-text-wrap">
                <label><input type="radio" id="currAppStatusYes" name="currAppStatusRadio" value="yes"> Yes</label>
                <label><input type="radio" id="currAppStatusNo" name="currAppStatusRadio" value="no"> No</label
                <label><input type="radio" id="currAppStatusMaybe" name="currAppStatusRadio" value="maybe"> Maybe</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('a#changeStatus').on('click', function(e) {

            // get the id of the current post and pass that to the modal window to find the correct fields for editing
                var rowid = jQuery(this).data('id');
                jQuery('.fetched-data').html(rowid);
            });
        });
     </script>
```

I think I need to use Ajax and possibly some other built in Wordpress functions but this is a little over my head. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I try your code and I have the good identifier in `.fetched-data`. that doesn't work with your tests ?

Comment: @mmm yes, I'm getting that data through but I'm not able to pass through something like `jQuery('.fetched-data').html(<?php the_title( rowid ); ?>);` to get the record's specific info to show. In the screenshot, where the modal window reads "Payroll Administrator," it should be Dolly Pardon or Fiona Apple (or any other applicant's name).

Comment: read the HTML source of this page. if you create more modals in a loop, all modal will have the identifier `modal` and then all link call (maybe) the last modal. the correct use for this modal is to be one time in the page. then in the link you add `data-title="Fiona"` and on the click you read the datas of the clicked link.

Comment: @mmm yup! I've only added the modal in once, outside of the loop. I understand how to pass static content through (using data-id or data-title, etc.), but I want to use the modal as a sort of "quick edit" space - so it needs to load the appropriate post's current radio button selection (if applicable) and then allow me to change and save it. That's where I'm at a stand-still.

Comment: This may be related: If you're trying to pass data from PHP to Javascript and back again, you should look into [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). ([Here's a tutorial.](https://wpshout.com/building-a-magical-golden-bridge-from-php-to-javascript-with-wp_localize_script/))

Comment: if I understand, between the page load and the moment when you click on "[change]", datas of the post can change ? then in this case, on the `click` event, you can use a AJAX call to retrieve the up-to-date datas. you can call a API endpoint to get theses datas : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/